# could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist

Tags: objective-c, build-error, cfbundleidentifier

somehow I came up with this build error:

> error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null)

how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your are not overriding the auto generated **Info.plist** file.

In my case I created ***Info.plist*** instead of ***< projectName>-Info.plist***
 which caused the mess.

for more about Info.plist:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html